# What is the Fourier transform of a sequence of random variables?

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis

I understand the Fourier transform of a signal f(t). It is an integral of f(t) times the Fourier basis. However, if f is a random function of t and $\omega$, what would be the fourier transform of f(t, $\omega$) represent?  ($\omega$ is an element from the sample space $\Omega$)

Blindly applying the integral generates a  random function which I could not quite wrap my mind around.

Comment: If $X_t$ (or $X_t(\omega)$ if you prefer) is a random variable indexed by $t$, then the moment generating function for $X_t$ is $g_t(r) = E[e^{rX_t}]$ for $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Or if you prefer, the characteristic function is $\phi_t(r) = E[e^{i r X_t}]$ which can be viewed as the Fourier transform of the density of $X_t$.

Comment: @Michael I am looking for some kind of integral w.r.t time so that I can look at it from the frequency domain.

Comment: It depends on what sequence of random variables you are considering - there isn't a generic answer.

Comment: @Math1000 well generic time series problem isnt it?